# How to dynamically change line width in Google Line Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, interactive

I have a complex line chart and would like to highlight (fatten) the line when moving the mouse over a dataset. The events "select" and "onmouseover" I can catch, but how do I dynamically change the line width of a dataset? Or are there other possibilities to highlight the selected line?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Customizing Lines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines#fullhtml) the line in Google Chart could be customized in two subtly different ways: with the `colors` option to change the chart palette, or with the `series` option to specify the color for particular series.

The following example demonstrates how to highlight line on selection event:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', { packages: ['corechart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

    data.addRows([
        [1, 37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2, 30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3, 25.4, 57, 25.7],
        [4, 11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5, 11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6, 8.8, 13.6, 7.7],
        [7, 7.6, 12.3, 9.6],
        [8, 12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9, 16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11, 5.3, 7.9, 4.7],
        [12, 6.6, 8.4, 5.2],
        [13, 4.8, 6.3, 3.6],
        [14, 4.2, 6.2, 3.4]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
            subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        series: {
            0: { lineWidth: 1 },
            1: { lineWidth: 1 },
            2: { lineWidth: 1 }
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() { highlightLine(chart,data, options); });

    chart.draw(data, options);
}


function highlightLine(chart,data,options) {
    var selectedLineWidth = 4;
    var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
    //reset series line width to default value
    for(var i in options.series) {
        options.series[i].lineWidth = 1;
    }
    options.series[selectedItem.column-1].lineWidth = selectedLineWidth; //set selected line width
    chart.draw(data, options);   //redraw
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I can use chart.draw() to just update the chart.

Comment: How do I use this code if I am adding annotation with each line data point?